# iOS collectionView cell sort order

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

in my app, I have a collection view in center of my screen, like this:
[image: collectionView]

but in my app I need that cell at indexpath.row 1 always be center of my screen. like this 
[image]

is there a solutions (in swift) for this situation?
thanks guys

Comment: Try adding insets to your collection view. Add insets on the left if you want to see the first cell centred. Also add insets to the right if you want the same centred behaviour on your last cell.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer thanks, but cllectionview cell always is center, my problem is I want to my second cell always be center when app launch

Comment: At the top of my head, I'd suggest overriding the scrollView delegate method `scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView:..., withVelocity velocity:..., targetContentOffset:...)`. You can do your own math here based on `targetContentOffset` (it will tell you at which `x` it will stop decelerating) and set it's `x`. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

**UICollectionViewFlowLayout** has 2 properties for insets:

**minimumInteritemSpacing**

**minimumLineSpacing**

Comment: not working for me, I want to my second cell always be center when app launch